# MariaDB - Unable to select the specified database: xxxx - after running a stored routine

Tags: mariadb

I'm using MariaDB 10.1.21 installed on Ubuntu 16.4.0 and Apache2 installed on the same machine.

My problem is that from a while, after I run a procedure that makes many INSERTs, I get the error `Unable to select the specified database: xxxx`

We recently changed both HDD into SSD, to eliminate any suspicions about the latency. 
However, even if the server's speed has been increased, .. I still get that MariaDB error.

I mention that the error persists for some seconds. After that, the web application is running ok , but the error may reapers from time to time until I restart the MySQL server.

The procedure body looks like here:
[MySQL INSERT INTO table SELECT FROM another_table, inside a PROCEDURE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44649657/mysql-insert-into-table-select-from-another-table-inside-a-procedure)

Any sugestion?

Answer (score 0):

Wherever possible, avoid using `CURSORs`.  SQL is designed to do things in bulk, not one row at a time.

Study constructs like

```
INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...;

CREATE TABLE ... SELECT ...;
```

Comment: I ended up creating a separate user to run that procedure.. however, now days that procedure has been changed and optimised due to updates of Maria DB new updates that made improvements in procedures. And Yes, all cursors had also been removed .